# Define custom sorting on free jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a column called InterestedValue, where I would like to allow sorting, by the label of the dropdown.

I found similar questions and I implemented the recommended solution, but it does not work.

Essentially, nothing happens, the applications behaves exactly like before we added the custom sorttype. Even adding alerts in it, nothing happens, get no errors, or anything.

```
{
    name: 'InterestedValue', editable: true, sortable: true, formatter: 'select', width: 110, search: false, edittype: 'select',
    editoptions: {
        value: InterestedStatusList,
    },
    sorttype: function (cellvalue)
    {
        return InterestedStatusList[cellvalue];
    }
}
```

I added the loadonce: true as suggested, and now I can sort the data correctly, but when I have more records than the ones shown in the first screen, I cannot visualize them.

My code is:

```
$(gridId).jqGrid(//'setGroupHeaders',
       {              
           url: actionMethod,
           shrinkToFit: false,
           datatype: 'json',
           mtype: 'GET',
           loadonce: true,
           //sortable: true,
           colNames: [MyColumns],
           colModel: [
           {MyModel }
           ],
           pager: jQuery(pagerId), //jQuery('#pager'),
           rowNum: 10,
           rowTotal: 2000,
           rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
           height: '100%',
           //width:700,
           viewrecords: true,

           caption: caption,
           emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
           jsonReader: {
           root: "rows",
           page: "page",
           total: "total",
           records: "records",
           repeatitems: false,
           Id: "0"
           },
           //autowidth: true,
           multiselect: false,
           gridview: true,
           editurl: '/InvestorList/Edit',
           onSelectRow: function (id) {

           if (id) { 
               $(gridId).jqGrid("editRow", id, true, '', '', '', '', reload)
               //ORIGINAL CODE: $(gridId).editRow(id, true,'', '', '', '', reload);
               lastSelectedId = id;

           }
           },
           serializeRowData: function (postdata) {
           //var response = JSON.stringify(postdata);
           var s = '';//'<select>';
           $(postdata).each(function (index, data) {
               //s += '<option value="' + index + '">' + data + '</option>';
               $.each(data, function (k, v) {
               if (k == "InterestedValue")
                   s += v;//'<option value="' + k + '">' + v + '</option>';
               });

           });
           //alert("s=" + s);
           if (s.indexOf("100010002") != -1) { //"2_1") {
               if (confirm('Are you sure you want to deactivate this record? ')) {
               // do things if OK
               return postdata;
               }
               else
               return false;
           }
           return postdata;

           },
```

Essentially I see the first ten records, and I have no way of accessing the remaining ones.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please **write in all questions** which version of jqGrid you use and which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You should always write which `datatype` you use and whether you use `loadonce: true`. It would be helpful if you include more JavaScript code or better if you create the demo ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo for example) with **some test data**, which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added the loadonce:true, but now I have problems with showing data when there are several page

Comment: If you add `loadonce:true` then you should change the server code so that it returns **all the data**. You don't need to implement server side paging.